# Checking if an integer is a circular prime number without using String

Tags: java, int, primes

I have to write a boolean method that checks if a number n is a circular prime, using only integer computations, so no Strings. I wrote two other methods that have to be included.

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
        for (int i = 3; i < n; i+=2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

This checks if the number is a prime.

```
int largestPowerOfTen(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n * 10; i*=10) {
        if (n / i == 0) {
            return i / 10;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This returns the largest power of ten of the number. For instance, 23 would return 10, 704 would return 100, etc.

I had the idea to put every digit into an array and move the digits around from there, but I'm stuck at the moving part.

```
boolean isCircularPrime(int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 0;

    while (n != 0) {
        k.add(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    //???
}
```

So how do I move the digits around?

Comment: You shouldn't need an ArrayList or a String: Calculate the last digit as `n` modulo 10. Divide `n` by 10 and round down. Add the last digit times `largestPowerOfTen(n)` to `n`. You should now have rotated `n` one spot to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a "circular prime number" is a number that is a prime number for all rotations of the digits...

You can't just rotate the number, because zeroes won't be conserved.

First break up the number into an array - each digit of the number an element of the array. Use `n % 10` to find the last digit, then `n /= 10` until `n == 0`.

Create a method the generates a number from the array with a specified starting index. This is the crux of the problem, and here's some code:

```
private static int generate(int[] digits, int index) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        result = result * 10 + digits[(index + i) % digits.length];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then loop over every possible starting index for your digits and check if it's prime.

The remaining code I leave to the reader...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CircularPrime
{
    public boolean prime(int n)
    {
        int lim=n,count=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=lim;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)count++;
        }
        if(count==2)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    public int circlize(int n)
    {
        int len,x,y,circle;
        len=(""+n).length();
        x=n/(int)Math.pow(10,len-1);
        y=n%(int)Math.pow(10,len-1);
        circle=(y*10)+x;
        return circle;
        /**
        Another way using String
        String str = Integer.toString(n);
        String arr = str.substring(1)+str.charAt(0);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(arr);
        return a;
        **/
    }
    public void check(int n)
    {
        int a=n;
        boolean flag=true;
        System.out.println("OUTPUT:");
        do
        {
            if(!(prime(a)))
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
            a=circlize(a);
            System.out.println(a);
        }while(a!=n);
        if(flag)System.out.println(n+" IS A CIRCULAR PRIME");
        else System.out.println(n+" IS NOT A CIRCULAR PRIME");
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        CircularPrime obj = new CircularPrime();
        Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        obj.check(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TT i am new on stack overflow, so i don't know how correct indentation.

Comment: You're welcome. You can review [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/273645) for some explanation on formatting on Stack Overflow.